# HTML5 audio not working in certain browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using these sounds for a game, so I am calling on them multiple times throughout the playing process via JQuery. In fireFox the sounds play fine but in Chrome and Safari they only play once each time.

```
<div class="audio-wrapper">

    <audio id="successSound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/cashtill.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'></source>
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/cashtill.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
    </audio>

    <audio id="failSound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/electric.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'></source>
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/electric.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
    </audio>

    <audio id="moveSound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/throw.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'></source>
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/throw.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
    </audio>

    <audio id="hitSound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/hit.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'></source>
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/hit.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
    </audio>

    <audio id="missSound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/miss.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'></source>
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/miss.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
    </audio>

    <audio id="audio-bg">
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/BGmusic.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'></source>
        <source src="sounds/games-sound-fx/BGmusic.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
    </audio>
</div>
```

In the script I call most of my sounds like this..

```
var successSound = $("#successSound")[0];
successSound.play();
```

But some of them have timeOut functions on them. Is there a better way to do it that supports all browsers properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are playing a sound, it plays on an audio channel.  With the code you listed, when you attempt to play a second sound, it will attempt to play on the same audio channel.  If the first sound hasn't finished at this point, it'll block the second being played.  The trick is to have a bit of Javascript that can tell if an audio element has finished playing & if not, use a different one.

Here's a URL with some good example code: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

Comment: I've had a go here using code from that article I linked to: http://jsfiddle.net/zXxGZ/11/ and it appears to work.  The flute sound lasts several seconds.  If you repeated press the play link it'll play again & again (up to 10 times anyway).  Are you able to edit your answer to include a fuller code sample if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks mate!! Do you know how I would fade a sound out? @
Lee Theobald

Comment: There's a volume attribute on the element. So like you can call `audio.play();` you can do something like `audio.volume = 0.2;` (where 0.2 is 20%).  To fade out, use setTimeout to gradually drop that volume level from 1 till it's 0.